# Vertically center a youtube video in container

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a responsive Youtube video which I've put in a container with a max-height. The video is cropped at the bottom. Is there a way to crop the top and the bottom equally so the video is centered vertically within the container and the play button is in the middle?

JS Fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3qtawjb7/

```css
.video-outer {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-outer">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/feLDAys0v-c"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a jQuery solution as the suggested answers weren't responsive.

```
  // vertically center video in iframe

  function centerVideo() {
    // get height of container
    $containerHeight = $( '.video-outer' ).height();
    $containerWidth = $( '.video-outer' ).width();
    $containerRatio = 360/640;

    // get height of video
    $videoHeight = $containerWidth * $containerRatio;

    // position video in center
    $heightDiff = $containerHeight - $videoHeight;
    $heightDiff = Math.round($heightDiff/2) + "px";
    $( '.video-container' ).css( 'top', $heightDiff );
  }

  // execute on load
  centerVideo();

  // recalculate on browser resize
  jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    centerVideo();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

should work like this:

```css
.video-outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 30%;        /* height has to be defined for my changes below*/
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-outer">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/feLDAys0v-c"></iframe>       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By setting the height rather than using max-height it means the video will be cropped into a portrait video on mobiles rather than just responding.

Answer (score 0):

How about JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p74oz13c/

I removed the:

```
<div class="video-outer"> ... </div>
```

... container completely, then added:

```
padding-top: -50%;
```

... to the .video-container style.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it does mean that on a mobile the video is going to be cropped to a portrait video, rather than responding.

Comment: True, @user2584163, I hadn't really considered responsiveness. :/

Comment: It also doesn't actually go full with when the video is played